# SUM column and delete old data after SUM

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL command that sums up 3 columns of incidents from 1 table and inserts into another table. It does the sum correctly as needed however in the 2nd table that it inserts into, it keeps the old data that it was summing up, is there a way that the data that it uses to sum up is deleted and the total stay in the table?

Here is the SQL Command I use for example:

```
INSERT INTO TotalIncidents([Name], IncA, IncB, IncC, DayOfData)
SELECT t.[Name], SUM(t.IncA), SUM(t.IncB), SUM(t.IncC), DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()) AS DayOfData
FROM TableA t
GROUP BY t.[Name]
```

I had thought of using a delete command by row count but I also noticed the data is not consistant meaning yesterday's data could show at top, then the day before yesterday's data can show at the bottom and today's data can show in the middile. perhaps I could add a order by statement to the end of my command to order the data then add a delete CTE command at the bottom kinda like this?

```
    INSERT INTO TotalIncidents([Name], IncA, IncB, IncC, DayOfData)
SELECT t.[Name], SUM(t.IncA), SUM(t.IncB), SUM(t.IncC), DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()) AS DayOfData
FROM TableA t
GROUP BY t.[Name] ORDER BY IncA, IncB, IncC Desc

WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Name] ORDER BY [Name]) AS RowNumber
    FROM TotalIncidents
    )
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RowNumber > 1
```

But this does rownumbers and not sure if I should go down this route. Any help appreciated as always.

---

Example Data:

```
NAME    |   IncA    |   IncB    |   IncC    |   Day
INC1        1           0           0           2016-01-03
INC1        0           2           0           2016-01-03
INC1        1           0           5           2016-01-03
INC1        1           7           3           2016-01-02
```

Would change to

```
NAME    |   IncA    |   IncB    |   IncC    |   Day
INC1        3           9           8           2016-01-03
```

Comment: Is TableA = TotalIncedents? If not, it doesn't look like you are filtering on anything in TableA, so is there a reason you can't use a `TRUNCATE TABLE` statement to delete all rows? `TRUNCATE` deletes everything from the table in one command vs. a `DELETE` statement that deletes row by row.  If they are the same, I will provide a different answer

Comment: what is the frequecny of inserts ?what is the frequency of deletes,so when you  insert a row,do you need to keep only that row ?

Comment: @WyattShipman good catch, yes I updated the question to reflect TableA = TotalIncidents. Not apposed to using Truncate just not completely familiar with it. Got any examples?

Comment: looks like you might want to select into #temp.. delete from table where name in #temp..  then insert sums

Comment: @TheGameiswar the frequency of inserts would be once daily, yes I only need to keep the row of which that is total of which it summed from.

Comment: @JamieD77 do you have any examples of how you would do this? I could only think of insert into temp table prior to sum, then do the insert into TotalIncidents after the calculation?

Comment: are you keeping a daily SUM?  what i mean is are you storing a record for every day for each [Name]?

Comment: no, just if there are incidents from before and 1 occurs today, it just adds that 1 for today into the total.

Say IncA has 6 incidents today it has 1, IncA should show 7 and the 1 needs to be deleted. The [Name] is the PK

Comment: In that case, i don't think my answer solves your issue. I think @JamieD77 solution works, you should maybe update the Date to get the max date in the group by. And you would also be able to Truncate the tables after selecting into the temp table since he isn't keeping a daily log, but a running count of incidents log. The bigger question here is, why doesn't your application just update the appropriate row's incident count instead of inserting and aggregating later.

Comment: @WyattShipman thank you very much for the clarification, and the update to the question that is a perfect example. Unfortunately my SQL Server went down now so I will test this once we get this back up for now I will test with another server and another database.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#tempIncidents') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #tempIncidents
END

SELECT  t.[Name],
        SUM(t.IncA) IncA,
        SUM(t.IncB) IncB,
        SUM(t.IncC) IncC,
        DATEADD(day,-1,GETDATE()) AS DayOfData
INTO    #tempIncidents
FROM    TotalIncidents t
GROUP BY t.[Name]
HAVING COUNT(t.[Name]) > 1


DELETE  FROM TotalIncidents
WHERE   [Name] IN (SELECT   [Name]
                   FROM     #tempIncidents)

INSERT  INTO TotalIncidents
        ([Name],
         IncA,
         IncB,
         IncC,
         DayOfData)
        SELECT  [Name],
                IncA,
                IncB,
                IncC,
                DayOfData
        FROM    #tempIncidents
```

this can be done inside of a transaction to prevent data loss due to errors.

Comment: Depending on how many summary rows are in this table, you might not want to have to delete/insert a bunch of additional rows that have already been aggregated and aren't changing.

Comment: @WyattShipman  this is true.. I would assume it would be based on `DayOfData` date field.. which would require and EXISTS() on the Select Into query

Comment: @JamieD77, "SUM() on a nullable column will give you NULL if any null values exist" - this is not true. `SUM` ignores `NULL` values. Only if all values in a column are `NULL`, the result will be `NULL`.

Comment: @JamieD77 This did run with no error, however nothing had changed, the data remained and did not delete. Also #tempIncidents becomes a permanent object within' SQL using SELECT..... INTO vs SELECT INTO, since it is not a table I cannot drop it. Maybe I'm missing something but this didn't seem to get it done

Comment: @Sam i thought you might be doing this inside of a Stored Procedure. If so, and you use Begin...End, the temp table will get deleted after the procedure is executed.  if not you can check to see if the temp table exists and drop it before you run Select...Into.. http://sqlserverplanet.com/tsql/drop-temp-table-if-exists

Comment: @JamieD77 I haven't really messed with stored procedures to say that I'm  comfortable using them. Thanks for the source link